# How to vectorise distance matrix calculations in R?

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have data that is in the form of a list stored in a string. There are around 7300 rows, and the lists are in the form `"23.53.24.33.55"` and so on.

Each of these numbers is a code for items and I'm calculating the [Sorensen-Dice distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) between the itemsets. There are 238 unique item codes.

I start with a dataset `matrix_ob.csv` which has 7300 rows and 239 columns where each list as shown above is onehotencoded into binary values indicating presence or absence of the item in the row (so in the example shown above there would be 233 zeroes and 5 ones for 23, 53,23,33 and 55). Initially I did this process using for loops but that worked earlier when the datasets were smaller, now I have so many rows that using a for loop seems incorrect. The distance matrix at the end would have dimensions of 7300x7300, which takes significantly longer to do.

I take the two lists that are being compared, and add the onehotencoded values. This means that each of the 238 binary values can take the values 0,1 or 2. 2 means the item code is present in both lists. If the itemsets are identical the distance is 0, if the itemsets are different, the distance is 1. The third ifelse case is when some of the items are present in both itemsets, for instance `"23.25.27"` and `"23.53.24.33.55"` have 1 item in common for both. I count the 0s, 1s and 2s and input them into the formula for the coefficient, and I get the Sorensen-Dice distance which is simply 1 minus the coefficient.

Currently this is the code I use:

```
sorensen_dice<-matrix(0, nrow = nrow(matrix_ob), ncol = nrow(matrix_ob))
for (i in c(1:nrow(sorensen_dice))) {
  for (j in c(1:nrow(sorensen_dice))) {
    if (i==j) {
      sorensen_dice[i,j] = 0
    }
    else {
      temp<-matrix_ob[i,]+matrix_ob[j,]
      if (length(table(list(temp)))==2) {
        sorensen_dice[i,j] = 1
      }
      else {
        a<-2*(table(list(temp))[[3]])
        bc<-table(list(temp))[[2]]
        p<-a+bc
        sorensen_dice[i,j] = 1-(a/p)
      }
    }
  }
  print(i)
} 

colnames(sorensen_dice)<-data_ob$LIST
rownames(sorensen_dice)<-data_ob$LIST
write.csv(sorensen_dice,file="sorensen_dice_ob.csv")
```

Each iteration out of 7000 takes a minute to execute which I see from the print line. However I don't understand how to vectorise something like this, there are no functions for this distance measure in R. What would be a good way to vectorise my calculations here? I'm essentially going 7000 times on a nested for loop to do this. I thought that maybe I could do it by only restricting the for loops to do one half of the matrix since this is a symmetrical matrix. This however just feels like a paperthin solution when I don't really understand properly how to vectorise something that's in a nested for loop.

Alternatively, the philentropy package has the distance() function which has the sorensen distance as well as the dice distance as options, which is the sorensen-dice distance?

Comment: The easiest way to speed your code is to not compute the index when comparing group1 with itself and to only compute group1/group2 and not group2/group1 assuming these are equivalent. That cuts the time in half. Alternatively there is a Sorenson-Dice function called `sorenson` in package [OmicsMarkeR](https://rdrr.io/bioc/OmicsMarkeR/f/inst/doc/OmicsMarkeR.pdf) .

Comment: since a matrix is a list, apply functions can be used , also the first if can be written as diag(soerensen_dice)=0 , and put outside of the for loops.

Comment: Yes, the package OmicsMarkeR helped.
As for using an apply function, how would you suggest I use apply for something like this?